# Carregar script a cada X segundos

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um Odometer em JS que é alimentado por um bloco de notas, então precisava fosse carregado o load.txt a cada 5 segundos mais ou menos...

tentei usar o setTime() mas não deu muito certo!

Segue a parte que gostaria que fosse executada a cada 5 segundos...

```js
$("odometer").load("counter.txt");
```

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 2):

Se você espera um comportamento recursivo, deveria utilizar a `setInterval()`

```js
function carregar()
{
  ///$("odometer").load("counter.txt");
  console.log('olar');
}

setInterval(carregar,5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```